# What's the System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension and the System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.Extension for?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees, expressionvisitor

The `System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor` has a method named `VisitExtension` which seems to do nothing other than call the `VisitChildren` method on the `Expression` being visited.

```
protected internal virtual Expression VisitExtension(Expression node)
{
    return node.VisitChildren(this);
}
```

I understand what the `VisitChildren` does. I also understand that this virtual implementation can be and is perhaps meant to be overriden. So I gather from the [documentation of the method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is sparing in words and briefly remarks:

*Visits the children of the extension expression.
This can be overridden to visit or rewrite specific extension nodes.
If it is not overridden, this method will call VisitChildren, which gives the node a chance to walk its children. By default, VisitChildren will try to reduce the node.*

I do not find this explanation helpful. Specifically, the phrase that jets me out of my abilities of comprehension is *"or rewrite specific extension nodes."*

I understand the rest of it, which pertains to the reduction or breaking down of the expression into sub-expressions.

Also in the same namespace is an enumeration named `ExpressionType`, the purpose of which I understand very well. But of all its members, there is one member named `Extension` which I cannot map to any syntactical token I am currently aware of.

The [documentation in this instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), too, is frustratingly laconic. It describes the value `Extension` as follows:

*An extension expression.*

It is obvious that the two -- `ExpressionType.Extension` and `ExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension` -- are related.

But what is an *extension*? Surely, as is glaringly obvious, extension methods have no place in this context. Which syntactical artifact does the expression *extension* refer to here?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.re-motion.org/blogs/mix/2010/02/18/net-4-0-expression-trees-extension-expressions/ ?

Comment: Thank you, Jeroen. From how the URL reads, it looks like it would have a very good answer to my question. However, I cannot open it. In fact, for quite some time now, a few months may be, I have not been able to open the re-motion project website. I was able to open it earlier last year.

Comment: For anyone interested, the last Internet Archive version of the link provided by @JeroenMostert is https://web.archive.org/web/20131013021401/https://www.re-motion.org/blogs/mix/2010/02/18/net-4-0-expression-trees-extension-expressions/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, extension does not represent any kind of built-in syntax, but correspond to nodes that applications can define and assign arbitrary meaning to.

That concept is very useful when one manipulates Expression trees in an application, as these extension nodes can be fully integrated into what is otherwise a normal expression tree.

For example, I defined a subclass of `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` with node type `ExpressionType.Extension` in order to extend Entity Framework's LINQ to understand the type of composite primary key that was in use at my company.

The extension expression type was useful because it let me use a two-step approach:

- In the first step, an expression visitor would regularize every appearance of that composite key into a node of my custom type;
- In the second step, the expression visitor that was tasked with translating the expression to something that Entity Framework would be able to handle could simply check on the type;

Example: let us say that I had LINQ code that was written:

```
from e in table where e.FirstKey == e.SecondKey select e;
```

Where `FirstKey` and `SecondKey` were both composite database keys (that is, there are two database columns `FirstKey1` and `FirstKey2` for `FirstKey`, and similarly for `SecondKey`).

Then the first visitor would transform both `e.FirstKey` and `e.SecondKey` to `CustomKeyExpression` nodes, functionally transforming it to:

```
from e in table where Key(e.FirstKey1, e.FirstKey2) == Key(e.SecondKey1, e.SecondKey2) select e;
```

And in the second visitor, when I would visit `EqualExpression`, I would check that both children were `CustomKeyExpression`s, and make the appropriate transformation:

```
from e in table where e.FirstKey1 == e.SecondKey1 && e.FirstKey2 == e.SecondKey2;
```

Comment: Thank you, Jean. Very well explained.